# How to access the input of username from htpasswd via JS?

Tags: javascript, access-control, .htpasswd

I used .htpasswd for access control on my webpage(HTML/JS). Now I want to get the input of username in htpasswd window. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a server-side script that knows how to interpret XHR POST requests and pass them into `htpasswd`, but people implement their own session management for a reason.